# Find row average of tuples in data frame / 2d array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2d array/pandas data frame like below:

```
          a         b         c
0    (1, 2)    (4, 4)  (10, 12)
1  (11, 10)  (44, 44)    (5, 6)
```

I would like to find out the row average in tuple form.
the desired output would be:

```
          a         b         c       avg
0    (1, 2)    (4, 4)  (10, 12)    (5, 6)
1  (11, 10)  (44, 44)    (5, 6)  (20, 20)
```

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way using `apply` inspired from `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412546/average-tuple-of-tuples`

```
df['avg'] = df.apply(lambda x: tuple(map(np.mean, zip(*x))),axis=1)
```

Another alternative:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist()).mean().round().agg(tuple),axis=1)

0      (5.0, 6.0)
1    (20.0, 20.0)
```

Or even better:

```
s  = df.stack()
df['avg'] = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),s.index).mean(level=0).round().agg(tuple,1)
print(df)

          a         b         c           avg
0    (1, 2)    (3, 4)  (10, 11)    (5.0, 6.0)
1  (12, 10)  (44, 44)    (5, 6)  (20.0, 20.0)
```

Answer (score 6):

I will do `map` for twice

```
list(map(lambda x : tuple(map(np.mean, zip(*x))), df.values.tolist()))
[(4.666666666666667, 5.666666666666667), (20.333333333333332, 20.0)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Certainly not the best way, but just for fun:

```
df['avg'] = (df.stack()
   .explode().astype(float)
   .reset_index(name='avg')
   .assign(group=lambda x: x.groupby(['level_0','level_1']).cumcount())
   .groupby(['level_0','group']).mean()
   .groupby(['level_0']).agg(tuple)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an interesting `apply` based solution.

```
df['result'] = df.applymap(np.array).apply(np.mean, axis=1).map(tuple)                                                                  
df                                                                  

          a         b         c        result
0    (1, 2)    (4, 4)  (10, 12)    (5.0, 6.0)
1  (11, 10)  (44, 44)    (5, 6)  (20.0, 20.0)
```

Not the greatest in terms of performance, though. You can argue against the use of apply, but then again you shouldn't be storing tuples in columns anyway. Here's a faster version using a list comprehension:

```
df['result'] = np.mean([
    [list(r_) for r_ in r] for r in df.values.tolist()], axis=1).tolist()                                           

df                                                                  
          a         b         c        result
0    (1, 2)    (4, 4)  (10, 12)    [5.0, 6.0]
1  (11, 10)  (44, 44)    (5, 6)  [20.0, 20.0]
```