# Finding the middle point of a given list of coordinates

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to write `def middle_point(coordinates)`, and each time I will be given list of coordinates (tuples) and it should return a tuple.

For example:

`coordinates = [(2,4),(2,0)]` **and I need to return** `(2,2)`

or another time:

`coordinates = [(2, 8, 7, 5), (6, 10, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4, 6)]` **and I need to return** `(3, 6.3, 4, 4.7)`

I know which formula I need to use, but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: If you know the formula you need to use, what's the problem?

Comment: Well, all the coordinates are given in a list, not seperate tuples, so I don't know how to get to each coordinate accordingly. I don't know how to add up: (x1+x2) for the first example or (x1+x2+x3) for the second example.

Comment: If you can use numpy, the easy way is to convert to numpy array, use `np.average` with `axis=0`, and if you need, convert output back to tuple.

Comment: More detail is needed on what you're trying to acheive and what you've tried so far.  Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edited my post so it's more comprehensive.

Comment: I think this question has already been answered comprehensively here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412546/average-tuple-of-tuples

Comment: I will take a look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use zip.

```py
coordinates = [(2, 8, 7, 5), (6, 10, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4, 6)]

result = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*coordinates)]
```

Comment: Thats a cool way - using `zip` to rotate the matrix :D

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I learned what '*' means. I haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = len(coordinates[0]) # Length of each coord
results = [0] * l # Convert to tuple at end

for coordinate in coordinates:
    for i in range(l):
        results[i] += coordinate[i] / l # Averaging points beforehand

results = tuple(results)
```

Comment: what does "results = [0] * l" this line mean?

Comment: It just pre-generates a list of `l` elements of `0` - the same as initialising a list in C#, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rotate the matrix 90 degree and return the average of each row.

```py
import numpy as np

q = [(2, 8, 7, 5), (6, 10, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4, 6)]

answer = [round(sum(x)/len(x),1) for x in np.rot90(q)][::-1]

print(answer)
```

or you could just use `np.average()` to do everything

```py
 print(np.average(q, axis=0))
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, although I can't use numpy for some reason. When I figure out how to use it I will thoroughly look at the code.